# Функция черчения линии по точкам C#

Tags: c#

Была создана функция для черчения линий между двумя выбранными вручную точками из девяти существующих, но проблема в том, что после рисования первой линии следующая линия ее затирает. В итоге на экране отображается только одна линия из всех. Понимаю, что функция постоянно создает новый Bitmap, и его нужно создать один раз за пределами метода и передавать в метод ссылку на него. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать в коде. Сама функция:

```
 public void Lines(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        Bitmap line = new Bitmap(pic1.Width, pic1.Height);
        Graphics l = Graphics.FromImage(line);
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black)
        {
            Width = 13
        };
        l.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
        pic1.Image = line;
    }
```

Comment: Вы знаете, как передать число в функцию, но не знаете, как передать `Bitmap`? Вы учили язык по видеоурокам?

Comment: @VladD а если действительно не знает и по видеоурокам? это простой, корректный и хорошо сформулированный(на удивление :) ) вопрос. U are not nice.

Comment: @Alias: Нет, я не nice. Я считаю, что нужно знать основы языка, а объяснять, как передавать параметр в функцию, как объявлять локальную переменную и что означает слово `int`, мне неохота. Если вам всё ещё охота — честь вам и хвала. Но с моей точки зрения автор вопроса должен прочитать хотя бы одну главу хотя бы одной книжки по языку. Поэтому по вопросам, ответ на которые есть в первой главе, я не отвечаю сам и других отговариваю.

Comment: @VladD согласен, но есть 1 важный момент, отличающих от оч.многих прочих: его код "как есть" вот так сразу нигде не гуглиться, человек действительно пытался сам решить задачу, и главное -- вопрос сформулирован неожиданно :) хорошо, без принудительных правок и пр., что КМК, с лихвой перекрывает его *простоту*.  А пошпынять очередного "сделайте-всё-за-меня" ещё всегда успеется :)

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что так вы *при каждом* вызове функции создаёте новый рисунок bitmap, рисуете в него *одну* линию с помощью такого же *одноразового* объекта Graphics, и в завершении *переприсваиваете* его изображению pic1.Image, при этом *затирая предыдущее*.

В начале вашей программы **единственный раз**: создайте рисунок `Bitmap`, объект рисования `Graphics` для него, назначьте этот рисунок соотв. свойству элемента отображения

```
Bitmap line = new Bitmap(pic1.Width, pic1.Height);
Graphics l = Graphics.FromImage(line);
pic1.Image = line;
//...получаем координаты для линий, и пр.
//затем рисуем столько линий, сколько надо:
Lines(l, x1, y1, x2, y2);//вызываем ф-ию рисования с требуемыми координатами, передавая ей параметром в т.ч. и объект рисования
Lines(l, x10, y10, x20, y20);//какая-то другая линия в тот же Bitmap
```

функция рисования минимально достаточная:

```
public void Lines(Graphics l, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black){ Width = 13  };//задать цвет и толщину линии
    l.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1, x2, y2);//нарисовать в связанный Bitmap.
}
```

Comment: Если из метода вынесен не только Bitmap, но и Graphics, тогда почему Pen оставлен внутри? / И хорошо бы дополнить про необходимость освобождения ресурсов: using/Dispose.